# How to return a list of elements in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to build a list of elements from a simple array in ELM. The expected result is literally just a list of elements with 1 as the first item, 2 as the second, and so on.

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class, id)
import List exposing (map)

theArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

createListItem item =
  li [] [ text (toString item)]

buildList collection =
  map createListItem collection

builtList = ul [] [(buildList theArray)]

main = 
  builtList
```

But I keep getting the compiler error on line thirteen. I've tried type annotating the map element to html but I don't see what I should do.

```
The 2nd argument to function `ul` is causing a mismatch.

 *13| builtList = ul [] [(buildList theArray)]*

Function `ul` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    List VirtualDom.Node

But it is:

    List (List Html)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`buildList` is already returning a value of type `List Html`, so you don't need brackets around `(buildList theArray)`. Change line 13 to:

```elm
builtList = ul [] (buildList theArray)
```